# Syntax to submit single git commit to Review Board using post-review

Tags: git, review-board

I want to create a Review Board review from a single commit.

When I use `post-review`, it submits all the diffs between my repo and master.

How do I limit this to a specific commit?  Or the files in a specific commit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out you need to use `--revision-range` with the git commits for before and after your change.  E.g.

```
 post-review --revision-range=f17f771:f5b67e3
```

Notice that I'm using a truncated value for the commit numbers.  Their actual values are f5b67e3978ec0348d33672ba79215fe887709bed and f17f7714f7e6c92fafb03bbfa3d7fefdb3295039.  However, I got the range from a git pull, which seems to report truncated numbers.

**Note:** Put the more recent commit last.

Comment: You got it. This can be a very useful tool. A note about the commit hashes: "Git is smart enough to figure out what commit you meant to type if you provide the first few characters, as long as your partial SHA-1 is at least four characters long and unambiguous — that is, only one object in the current repository begins with that partial SHA-1." (see [http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html])

Comment: It is very userful. It should be noted that the range doesn't include the start commit while the end commit is included, namely (, ].

Answer (score 4):

You can use following command to send a particular commit in review request

```
rbt post d1c631b
```

Note: Here `d1c631b` is truncated commit id not the actual commit id.

Answer (score 1):

I was annoyed by having to know two commit ids.
So I wrapped this into a little bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# I called the file git-review

SHA=$1
shift
post-review --revision-range=$(git rev-parse $SHA^):$(git rev-parse $SHA) $*
```

The `git rev-parse` will translate any branch or tag into it's commit id.
hence if you are in the repository you can do `git-review HEAD -i my_reviewer`

The shift operation will make sure that the refspec will not be passed twice to the command line.

**NOTE**: calling the file git-review has the side effect of it being visible to git and you can call then `git review HEAD`